# onLoad="MyOnLoad"

Tags: vba

does anybody have any idea what's does this mean: onLoad="MyOnLoad"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnLoad is an event that occurs when a control has been created. The MyOnLoad method will be called when the control has been created and added to the window/form.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a Subprocedure `MyOnLoad` which is being called on when the `onLoad`-event occurs.